# Printing items within a list within a list, etc. (Printing nested lists)

Tags: python, directory

I'm trying to write a function that will basically print:

```
file1

file2

file3

file4

file5

file6

file7
```

When I enter:

```
C = [['file1', [['file2']], ['file3', 'file4', 'file5']], 'file6', ['file7']]
```

It's supposed to be like a directory.

Here is my code:

```
def tree_traverse(directory) :

    list1 = list(directory)
    for it in list1 :
        if it == 'Cc' :
            del(list1[:(list1[it]+3)])
    for item in directory :
        print(item)
```

Whenever I enter the input above, I get an error saying C is an unexpected argument.
Also, when I enter the above input without the "C = ", it just prints it like I entered it.
I'm quite lost at what to do.

Comment: ... An unexpected argument to *what*?

Comment: @Ignacio this is the error I get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 1, in <module>
    tree_traverse(C = [['file1', [['file2']], ['file3', 'file4', 'file5']], 'file6', ['file7']])
TypeError: tree_traverse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'C'

Comment: Related : [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

This flattens the list as you want.

```
C = [['file1', [['file2']], ['file3', 'file4', 'file5']], 'file6', ['file7']]

def getFiles(container):
    for f in container:
        if isinstance(f, list):
            for fArray in getFiles(f):
                yield fArray
        else:
            yield f

print "".join("%s\n" %f for f in list(getFiles(C)))
```

Comment: What if it has more than two layers?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code. I didn't realize you had a recursive method (this is what I get for trying to skim code late at night). +1, I actually really like your answer

Answer (score 0):

The function has no argument called `C` therefore you cannot pass it a [**keyword argument**](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) called `C`. Either use `directory=...` instead or pass it the object as a normal argument.

```
C = ...
tree_traverse(C)
```

Comment: Okay, that works better, but I'm still unsure how to print each individual nested item.

Answer (score 0):

Using a recursive method (that should work for an indefinite number of layers):

```
def print_list(obj, final_string=""):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for itm in obj:
            final_string = print_list(itm, final_string)
        return final_string
    else:
        return final_string + "\n" + obj

print print_list(c)
```